# Infragistics DockManager sizing two TabGroupPanes

Tags: wpf, infragistics

I have a XamDockManager with two document tabs, driven by Prism regions, like so:

```
        <igDock:DocumentContentHost>
            <igDock:SplitPane igDock:XamDockManager.InitialLocation="DockedLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <igDock:TabGroupPane x:Name="SelectorPane" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.SelectionRegion}">
                </igDock:TabGroupPane>
                    <igDock:TabGroupPane>
                        <igDock:ContentPane x:Name="GridPane" AllowClose="False" CloseButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                                    Header="...">
                            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ContentRegion}"/>
                        </igDock:ContentPane>
                   </igDock:TabGroupPane>
            </igDock:SplitPane>
        </igDock:DocumentContentHost>
    </igDock:XamDockManager>
```

I have my adapter working, everything is functional.

However.

As defined above, both panes are the same size, with a splitter in the center. I don't want that, so I add `Width="400"` to the first (left-hand) `TabGroupPane`... and all of a sudden, I have no more splitter. The connection between the panes is completely lost.

How can I specify the width of the left pane without losing the splitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough: add `igDock:SplitPane.RelativeSize="..."` to the `TabGroupPane` declarations.

Derp.